# Ascii character encoding issue

Tags: c, ascii

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char line[80];
    int count;
    // read the line of charecter
    printf("Enter the line of text below: \n");
    scanf("%[ˆ\n]",line);
// encode each individual charecter and display them
    for(count = 0; line[count]!= '\0'; ++ count){
        if(((line[count]>='0')&& (line [count]<= '9')) ||
           ((line[count]>= 'A')&& (line[count]<='Z')) ||
           ((line[count]>= 'a')&& (line[count]<='z')))
            putchar(line[count]+1);
        else if (line[count]=='9')putchar('0');
        else if (line [count]== 'A')putchar('Z');
        else if (line [count]== 'a') putchar('z');
        else putchar('.');
    }
}
```

In the above code problem is converting encoding. Whenever I compile the code, the compiler automatically converts the encoding and then I am unable to get required output. 
My target output should look like:

```
enter the string
Hello World 456
Output
Ifmmp.uif.tusjof
```

For every letter, it is replaced by 2nd letter and space is replaced by '`.`'.

Comment: Your output translates *back* to "Hello the string". Is that what you were supposed to do?

Comment: Your desired output seems to correspond to the text "`Hello the strine`" and not "`Hello World 456`" as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

This is suspect:

```
scanf("%[ˆ\n]",line);
```

It should be:

```
scanf("%79[^\n]",line);
```

Your version has a multibyte character that looks a bit like `^`, instead of the `^`. This would cause your scans to malfunction. Your symptoms sound as if the text that has been input is actually multi-byte characters.

BTW you could make your code easier to read by using `isalnum( (unsigned char)line[count] )`. That test replaces your a-z, A-Z, 0-9 tests.

Comment: That Bad Special Character catch is *very* well spotted! The OP must have used a Dead Key code -- Option+i on my Mac -- to get `ˆ` instead of the usual Shift+6 (on an US keyboard), the key helpfully marked  with "6 ^".

Comment: Possibly using a goofy editor that "helpfully" replaces boring old ascii characters with nice-looking unicode ones.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking your conditions correctly:

```
if (line[count]>= 'A')&& (line[count]<='Z)
  ..
```

*already* converts the character 'Z'. The next check,

```
if (line [count]== 'A')putchar('Z');
```

is never executed. But that is not the only thing wrong here. The character 'A' should be translated to 'B', not 'Z'. You probably want

```
if (line[count]>= 'A' && line[count] < 'Z)
```

(`<` instead of `<=`) and

```
if (line [count]== 'Z')putchar('A');
```

and the same for lowercase and digits.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your format string for `scanf`. If you want to read a line of text from the console, you should use `%s`.

If you want to make sure that you read a maximum of 79 characters, you should use `%79s` (because your line vector has a length of 80).

So you should replace your scanf with this:

```
scanf("%79s", line);
```

Comment: The `s` modifier stops on whitespace; the `[` modifier only stops on the listed characters.